Any way to stop Ubuntu update?
So I'm using a flash drive to load Ubuntu, and I clicked the "Update Ubuntu" button, and it's been loading for so long. It's been another 3 hours (I had to wait 3 hours before to download it) waiting for it to update after installing it.
I have Ubuntu on the flash drive (3.0), so I don't think that it will damage the SSD, but how would I stop the update with the least risk?
This is a new device and I am downloading Ubuntu on a flash drive, with Rufus on another. I clicked the update button on the flash drive with the full Ubuntu, and it's staying on the update screen.
I'm using 24.04 LTS

Oh, I'm using 24.04 LTS. I used this video and it's stuck at the loading screen. It's a moderately fast USB, so it shouldn't be taking so long. I used 2 USBs, but didn't really understand Rufus and downloading Linux the first time. The first time was slow, but when I downloaded the ISO the second time it went faster. Any more info you need? (All components are new and functioning properly)

@user68186 I have updated the question. I have installed the ISO file on USB1 while downloading the full Ubuntu on USB2. It's stuck on the boot screen. I do believe it has something to do with the speed of the flash drive, but is there any way I can turn off the computer and cancel the update?

@user68186 I finished the installation, but when I booted the finished installation  from USB2, it became stuck at the same screen for now I think 6 hours. I already finished the USB2 download from USB1.

@karel, thanks! How would I redownload Ubuntu and is my computer safe to turn off? I'm guessing I'll just have to reformat  USB2, the one with the full OS, but would I need to do anything else to turn off my computer and get Ubuntu running?

It seems like the underlying problem is that your BIOS's boot priority settings do not recognize your USB flash drive as a bootable device.
Your computer is safe to turn off by holding down the power button of the computer for a few seconds.
Whether or not you can successfully install Ubuntu so that it will run from your USB flash drive is problematic. The main problem with running Ubuntu from a USB flash drive is that there are two hardware components to consider - the computer that is powering the USB flash drive and the USB flash drive itself. If either component has an underlying hardware issue then Ubuntu running on the USB flash drive may suffer from degraded performance. Degraded performance is not such a big issue if you are using a USB flash drive for Ubuntu installation media, but it can be critical if you are using the USB flash drive for installing the Ubuntu operating system on it. In the past few years portable SSDs have become cheap, and are more suitable than USB flash drives for running Ubuntu on an external hard drive.

oh, sorry if I didn't clarify. When I inserted the flash drive into the computer, went into my BIOS, went into the Ubuntu launch thing, like in the ISO flash drive when you turn it on, the first button is "Update Ubuntu" and when I clicked on it (No other options made a lot of sense), it took me to the loading screen with the company manufacturer (Asus ROG was mine) and the Ubuntu logo and wheel near the bottom, and it never went out. I have no GUI and no mouse to interact with, almost as if it was booting.

Thank you so much!
